#  How can I get customErrors' defaultRedirect value from code?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, custom-errors

I would simply like to do something as follows:

```
var defaultRedirectUrl = SomeMethodToGetDefaultRedirect();
```

of course in web.config I have

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error"/>
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanx mark, it was helpful.
What I really wanted to ask was "how to get "defaultRedirect" property of customErrors section from web.config of my asp mvc app?".

And the answer, based on your post is:

```
    CustomErrorsSection customErrorsSection = (CustomErrorsSection) ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/customErrors");
        string defaultRedirect = customErrorsSection.DefaultRedirect;
```

Answer (score 12):

If I understand your question correctly, this should help (copied from msdn)

```
// Get the Web application configuration.
Configuration configuration =  WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration( "/aspnetTest");

// Get the section.
CustomErrorsSection customErrorsSection = (CustomErrorsSection)configuration.GetSection("system.web/customErrors");

// Get the collection
CustomErrorCollection customErrorsCollection =  customErrorsSection.Errors;

// Get the currentDefaultRedirect
string currentDefaultRedirect =  customErrorsSection.DefaultRedirect;
```